# Advanced Taxonomy Queries Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am working with wordpress and business listings.  I have about 5000 business listing all over the usa.  Each business listing has a custom field for state, county and city and brands.

My business listings are car dealers and each dealer is loaded into my wordpress database under a custom post type called dealers.

I have created two taxonomies called geography (logical structure = states ->county->city) and brands (ie. Honda, Toyota)  to be able to view dealers by different queries options.
It is my understanding I can query between the geography and brands taxonomy with parameters and I have that part working.   For instance, www.xyz.com/dealers/?geography=alabama&brands=toyota.  This query would list a category page of all dealers in my database in the state of Alabama with a brand of Toyota.

I now need to create dynamic category pages for hundreds of different query options by geography and brands.  Here are the options:

1. All dealers by each state in the USA
2. All dealers by each county in USA
3. All dealers by each city in USA
4. All dealers by each brand
5. All dealers by each brand and state in the USA
6. All dealers by each brand and county in USA
7. All dealers by each brand and city in USA

I assume I can create a category template in wordpress for each of the above option.
But I am just a little confused how this would work in wordpress.

Can someone provide me some guidance on how this might work for creating the category pages.  Secondly is this a good solution for what I am trying to accomplish or is there a better way?

Also one more note, when viewing different category pages I would need certain navigation items to be specific to that query.

For instance for geography the logical drill down on the navigation would be from state to county to city.  So when I am viewing the Alabama category page the next level of navigation would need to be counties in Alabama that have dealer records in my database.  Likewise when viewing dealers in California category page the next level of navigation would need to be counties in California that have dealer records in my database.

Your assistance is very much appreciated.